# Como montar este array-multidimensional via foreach

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Vou colocar somente a parte onde estou tendo problemas!

O `array` que necessito, precisa ser neste formato.
***Exemplo 1:***

```
Array
(
    [atributos] => Array
        (
            [atributo] => Array
                (
                    [nome] => Tamanho
                    [valor] => 35
                ),

            [atributo] => Array
                (
                    [nome] => Cor
                    [valor] => AZUL/ROSA
                )

        )

)
```

Porém o máximo que cheguei perto foi este!
***Exemplo 2:***

```
Array
(
    [atributos] => Array
        (
            [atributo] => Array
                (
                    [nome] => Cor
                    [valor] => AZUL/ROSA
                )

        )

)
```

Vamos ao real problema, se tenho dois ou mais atributos dentro do array:

```
$arrayAtributos = array('Tamanho' => 35, 'Cor' => 'AZUL/ROSA');
```

Ao fazer leitura do com `foreach`, para que possa adicionar os índices e valores junto aos nó, **"atributos/atributo"**

```
$arrayAtributos = array('Tamanho' => 35, 'Cor' => 'AZUL/ROSA');

foreach ($arrayAtributos as $nome => $valor) {

     $xmlArray['atributos']['atributo']['nome'] = $nome;
     $xmlArray['atributos']['atributo']['valor'] = $valor;

}

print_r($xmlArray);
```

Somente o ultimo índice é adicionado ao array, ignorando o restante, como se desse um **group by nome + valor**

Como é que se faz, para que todos os atributos sejam adicionados dentro deste array-multidimensional utilizando o `foreach`, como no primeiro exemplo?

Modelo completo do XML e já sendo gerado corretamente com apenas um atributo!

http://pastebin.com/y28VHAwT

Mas preciso adicionar mais atributos como no exemplo:

```
<atributos>
      <atributo>
           <nome>Tamanho</nome>
           <valor>35</valor>
      </atributo>
      <atributo>
           <nome>Cor</nome>
           <valor>AZUL/ROSA</valor>
      </atributo>
</atributos>
```

E está ficando somente com e último atributo do array

```
<atributos>      
     <atributo>
           <nome>Cor</nome>
           <valor>AZUL/ROSA</valor>
     </atributo>
</atributos>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde,

Dependendo de como estás a gerar o xml (Ferramenta que usas), poderá ser que o seguinte funcione:

```
$arrayAtributos = array('Tamanho' => 35, 'Cor' => 'AZUL/ROSA');

foreach ($arrayAtributos as $nome => $valor) {
    $detalhes = array(
        'nome' => $nome,
        'valor' => $valor,
    );

    $xmlArray['atributos']['atributo'][] = $detalhes;
}
```

Se desta forma não resultar no que é pretendido, poderás experientar utilizar esta [biblioteca](https://github.com/MASNathan/Parser):

```
$ composer require masnathan/parser
```

O encode da array seria feito do seguinte modo:

```
Parser::data($xmlArray)->setPrettyOutput(true)->to('xml');
```

Apenas experimentei com os dados que colocaste aqui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<atributos>
  <atributo>
    <nome>Tamanho</nome>
    <valor>35</valor>
  </atributo>
  <atributo>
    <nome>Cor</nome>
    <valor>AZUL/ROSA</valor>
  </atributo>
</atributos>
```

Comment: Show de bola está Biblioteca @MASNathan, valeu por compartilhar, encaixou como uma luva!

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Coringa,
Sim o problema está nesta secção

```
foreach ($arrayAtributos as $nome => $valor) {

     $xmlArray['atributos']['atributo']['nome'] = $nome;
     $xmlArray['atributos']['atributo']['valor'] = $valor;

}
```

Deveria ser assim:

```
$x = 0;
foreach ($arrayAtributos as $nome=> $valor) {
        $xmlArray['atributos'][$x]['nome'] = $nome;
        $xmlArray['atributos'][$x]['valor'] = $valor;
        $x++;
}
```

Isto resulta, não vejo grande logica no array que queres construir mas como não sei como está o resto do codigo sei que isto funciona. Eu colocaria os atributos como indexes do novo array.

Exemplo:

```
Array
(
    [atributos] => Array
        (
            [tamanho] => 35,
            [cor] => AZUL/ROSA
        )

)
```

Isto faz me mais sentido. 
Mas a solução que coloquei funciona.

Cumprimentos.

Comment: Bom dia @Wilson, é quase isso, e sobre o XML, é do Buscapé, é bem grande o código, ai só coloquei a parte que está dando este pequeno problema, no seu código gera um índice, e este indice gera outro erro. segue o xml gerado http://pastebin.com/y28VHAwT

Comment: Então o array tem que manter esta estrutura certo?

$xmlArray['atributos']['atributo']['nome'] = $nome;
$xmlArray['atributos']['atributo']['valor'] = $valor;

Comment: Sim, teria alguma ideia, e quase isso, mas sem os índices!, igual ao primeiro exemplo! Obrigado.

Comment: <categoria>camiseta</categoria>
         <disponibilidade>1000</disponibilidade>
         <altura>20.5</altura>
         <comprimento>80.5</comprimento>
         <largura>40.5</largura>
         <peso>305</peso>
         <especificacoes>

Da mesma maneira que há isto no XML não poderia haver mais 2 tags chamadas:
<tamanho>35</tamanho>
<cor>azul</cor>

Comment: Não entendi o copy!

Comment: Se reparares no XML existe varios atributos espalhados como: 'categoria', 'disponiblidade', 'altura' etc... Será que também não suporta atributos como: 'tamanho' e 'cor'? Eu não sei como funciona o XML do buscapé.

Comment: Eu segui o modelo da Plataforma, veja o [link](http://developer.buscape.com.br/portal/developer/tutoriais/como-montar-o-xml-para-carga-de-produtos.html), tem justamente os dois atributos e da forma como tem que ser passado.

Comment: Tens toda a razão, mas então não estou a ver solução. O PHP tu não vais conseguir fazer um array como no 1º exemplo porque os indexes do array estão iguais nos 2.. Só se enviares a 1ª parte do array e dps envias a outra.. nem sei se dá para fazer isto...

Comment: Ok Wilson Obrigado pela ajuda, vou ver o que eu faço, ou se aparece alguém com alguma nova sacada, mas acho que é como você falou, os indexes são iguais! vlw